# Can i make HTML forms in Django without using django forms API and Model Forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

If yes, what the pros and corns
if no, what the pros and corns

Actually, I want to build HTML forms without the Django Form API and ModelForm

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can, but then you need to maintain by hand the fields you would like, handle validation on the server side and probably a lot more. In short, it's a lot of work. If you want to write custom html around the fields it's possible so there is no reason to write a whole form from scratch. What are you trying to achieve?